# Run Gatbsy Buil periodically in crontab

Tags: npm, cron, gatsby

I would need to recreate my site in gatsby (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) every hour using crontab.

I created a simple script in the project folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html && \
npm run build
```

And created a crontab ( currently every minute )

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/build.bash 1> /dev/null 2> /home/user/test.txt
```

If I run the script directly it works fine, but when run from crontab I get an error:

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/loggers/ink/index.js:13111
   const lineNumber = location?.start.line;
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: I am also facing similary issue. Mostly gatsby is getting run with some old node version. hence it is not recongnising modern "?." syntax but I am yet to find a solution yet.